# rsync - any issues kicking off another rsync while one is already running?

Tags: cron, rsync

Kind of a stupid question, but I'm just covering my bases and I haven't found anything with a quick google search. I have an rsync that runs hourly and is kicked off by a cron. Then once a week I need kick this rsync off from another script to make sure I have the latest files I need.

What happens if the rsync is already running from the cron and I kick the same rsync off again? In a quick test it looks like the second rsync picks up where the first left off, but I want to be sure so I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rsync will run independently and will take their own "snapshots" of the local and remote sides to compare. I think in many cases where you are just pushing updates from one side to the other you will probably be fine, the only caveat being you many end up transferring duplicate data.